# How to add custom validation rule to billing address field Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, validation, billing-address

I am using magento 2.1.7. I have added vat field to billing address form. I want to add custom field validation. i have added below code.

[image]

Added below validation to phtml file

[image]

But my custom validation not working. Magento required field validation is working fine. Can anyone help me.

Comment: Hi @Prashant , didd you found the solution

Comment: @sri as per given answer i have override rules js file. add your custom validation to override js file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override rules.js using below code in my custom module

**app/code/Test/Custom/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    "map": {
        "*" : {
            'Magento_Ui/js/lib/validation/rules' : 'Test_Custom/js/validation/rules'
        }
    }
};
```

created js file at
 **app/code/Test/Custom/view/frontend/web/js/validation/rules.js**

Run **php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy** command.

Comment: great, it works! Haven't you found another way without override rules.js?

Comment: There is mixin concept but that is not working in my case. Please try with mixin

Comment: yes, i could try to override rules.js, thx very much