# Magento 2 how to add extra validation to new Billing address form fields in checkout page

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, validation, billing-address

i want to put some extra validation to **billing address** form in checkout page. When a **customer** in payment page and **wants to add new billing address** , i want to add few **validations** to **First Name, Last Name and Phone Number fields**,

[image]

How can i add it ? i did the same validation for shipping address form in checkout_index_index.xml. But i am unable to find anything related to billing address form,
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Just follow this path in **checkout_index_index.xml**

But you need to specify validators in each form. Or you can try to use layoutProcessor [like here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/215082/how-to-add-custom-validation-rule-to-billing-address-field-magento-2) going through the loop and reffer to paymend method via its **$keyCode**.

Also I found that rule **max_text_length** does not work properly on billing forms but works perfectly in shipping forms. I ended up with creating own validation rule.

You can find all rules here **Magento_Ui/js/lib/validation/rules.js**

Be careful with rules form **mage/validation.js** they don't work on chekout and vice versa (*please correct me if I am wrong*) so it's the reason why I tried to use **max_text_length** instead of **validate-length maximum-length-35**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="payments-list" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <!-- Billing forms start -->
                                                                <!-- Pay attention that you need to set form validators for each payment method-->
                                                                <item name="cashondelivery-form" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="form-fields" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                <!-- form fields here -->
                                                                                <item name="company" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                        <item name="max_text_length" xsi:type="number">35</item>
                                                                                    </item>
                                                                                </item>
                                                                                <item name="telephone" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                        <item name="max_text_length" xsi:type="number">15</item>
                                                                                        <item name="min_text_length" xsi:type="number">7</item>
                                                                                        <item name="no-whitespace" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                                    </item>
                                                                                </item>
                                                                                <item name="postcode" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                        <item name="max_text_length" xsi:type="number">9</item>
                                                                                    </item>
                                                                                </item>
                                                                                <item name="region_id" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                        <item name="max-string-length" xsi:type="number">35</item>
                                                                                    </item>
                                                                                </item>
                                                                                <item name="firstname" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                        <item name="max_text_length" xsi:type="number">35</item>
                                                                                    </item>
                                                                                </item>
                                                                                <item name="lastname" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                        <item name="max_text_length" xsi:type="number">35</item>
                                                                                    </item>
                                                                                </item>
                                                                                <item name="city" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                        <item name="max_text_length" xsi:type="number">35</item>
                                                                                    </item>
                                                                                </item>
                                                                                <item name="street" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                        <item name="0" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                                <item name="max_text_length" xsi:type="number">35</item>
                                                                                            </item>
                                                                                        </item>
                                                                                        <item name="1" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                                <item name="max_text_length" xsi:type="number">35</item>
                                                                                            </item>
                                                                                        </item>
                                                                                        <item name="2" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                                <item name="max_text_length" xsi:type="number">35</item>
                                                                                            </item>
                                                                                        </item>
                                                                                    </item>
                                                                                </item>
                                                                            </item>
                                                                        </item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                <!-- Billing forms end -->
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: How to make only numbers allowed in telephone field

Comment: @ChethanSreenivasaMurthy there is a few options. Set input type "number" or if you want to validate special format or allow users to enter "+" then you need to create custom validation rule for JS e.g. `return $.mage.isEmptyNoTrim(value) || /^\+?[0-9]{4,15}$/.test(value);` Or apply native magento validator `validate-number` But don't forget about back-end validation